# PHP Multidimenstional Associative Array Search by Value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array where I want to search the name and get the key of the array that its associated to.

## **Examples**

Assume we have the following 2-dimensional array with the second dimension being associated to a key:

```
$leaderboard = array(
    029102938093028 => array(
        'Rank' => '1st',
        'Name' => 'HenryB',
        'Kills' => 10,
        'Deaths' => 4,
        'Headshots' => 5
    ),
    029382912873929 => array(
        'Rank' => '2nd',
        'Name' => 'Will R',
        'Kills' => 6,
        'Deaths' => 4,
        'Headshots' => 1
    ),
    0283928293898303 => array(
        'Rank' => '3rd',
        'Name' => 'Robert M',
        'Kills' => 3,
        'Deaths' => 10,
        'Headshots' => 0
    ),
);
```

The function call search_by_uid("HenryB") (name of the first user) should return 029102938093028 (The key of the array).

The function call search_by_uid("Robert M") should return 0283928293898303.

I have seen examples using multidemensional arrays where it returns the index but never the associated index. Please close if repeat question that i am unable to find.

Comment: Missing apostrophe after Robert M

Comment: @RAZERZ Thank you fixed.

Comment: are you aware how PHP handles numbers in arrays?

Comment: @RAZERZ I believe so? This is just the output of the array when i print_r it. So my understanding may be mistaken.

Comment: Ah alrighty. Not sure which PHP version you are using but for future proofing, stringify your integers (eg. 0283928293898303 becomes '0283928293898303'). How familiar are you with forEach loops in php?

Comment: @RAZERZ Ah okay, i am used 7.4 currently. I will do that for the future. I am rather familiar they just loop through each item in a array or other data structures.

Comment: Awesome! Let me sketch up a function and I'll post it as a result

Comment: if I understood correctly, you need to create a simple function which handles you array in foreach loop, compare name to target and returns key if comparison was success. Is it true?

Comment: @AndrewMarkhai Yes, thats it. Getting the Key was the part is was struggling with.

Comment: `foreach ($leaderboard as $key => $item) {
            if ($item['Name'] === 'HenryB') {
                return $key;
            }
        }
        return false;`

Comment: o, you already have the answer like my comment)

Comment: @AndrewMarkhai Thank you. Yes Answer below Describes it. Yours is the implementation thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$leaderboards = array(
    '029102938093028' => array(
        'Rank' => '1st',
        'Name' => 'HenryB',
        'Kills' => 10,
        'Deaths' => 4,
        'Headshots' => 5
    ),
    '029382912873929' => array(
        'Rank' => '2nd',
        'Name' => 'Edward B',
        'Kills' => 6,
        'Deaths' => 4,
        'Headshots' => 1
    ),
    '0283928293898303' => array(
        'Rank' => '3rd',
        'Name' => 'Robert M',
        'Kills' => 3,
        'Deaths' => 10,
        'Headshots' => 0
    ),
);

function search_by_uid($array, $name) {

    foreach ($array as $index => $value) {
        if($value["Name"] === $name) {
            return $index;
        }
    }

}

echo search_by_uid($leaderboards, 'Robert M'); //Returns 0283928293898303
```

Using a foreach loop to loop through all the values in the array until matching value is found, then the index is returned and the loop stops.